# Crash in a simple C# metro app with error code 0x5d039293

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

My project was created upon the C# Grid template project. Only the Layout and the data are different. In the item Detail page, there 5 images and one article. by proceeding the actions: enter one item Detail page, then back, and reenter it, then back, after several steps(10 steps if fast), the app crashes.

**Notice:** It is OK in Desktop, but will happen in the monitor, and also the device(pad). The last one is the reason why the app can't pass the windows store certification.

Below is the error reported in VS 2012 with win 8 RTM:

> FatalExecutionEngineError
>
> **Message:** The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x5d039293, on thread 0x1a84. The error code is 0x80131544. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

anyone can help?

PS: This is a very very simple project, and I even created one via the template, just changed the layout of the item detail page and added the images and text to load. So of course it did not use some wrong/crazy/ridiculous code, even not access the web. in the loadState/saveState method, you can reference the C# Grid template.

Comment: I've seen this on Windows 7 using .NET 4 as well.. (So it's not metro or Win8 or .NET 4.5 specific) It pretty much means you're doing something wrong/crazy/ridiculous in your code which corrupted the stack. (so the debugger or the CLR itself don't know which line you crashed) Sorry, I can't remember how I fixed it.
My advise is to debug step by step, pay more attention to how you access the UI elements (from other threads ?) do you use any WCF services ? and access UI on a callback ? Worst case, you may be calling a WinRT API in a way you're not 'supposed' to.

Comment: You are not alone on this one: https://twitter.com/Arktronic/status/237236310639788034 maybe you should post a zip of your code on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/c1582676-6936-45f4-8739-b83a1a632cc1

Comment: The error code is unusual, surely it is specific to the WinRT language projection.  You'll need to document the problem better to get anywhere.  At least a stack trace is required with unmanaged debugging and the Microsoft symbol server enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what I ran into last night, actually. It is well known from recent release previews and is still persistent. There is no known solution, and you can't catch and handle the error, nor can you debug it. It's a total explosion.

The issue can sometimes be worked around by adding an element, such as a border, around images in your application.

It has something to do with navigating between separate pages and image load/animation events. For my project, I simply reduced my navigation and had all of my substantial effort take place on one page, programatically adding and removing elements as necessary, to avoid frame.navigate

See the following:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/0dcffd79-3848-4cc3-839d-ab7d3544f80a